# unexpected additional columns

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

in most of my tables, command

```
SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name='table'
```

worked as expected, but in one table i am getting additional tables that i was not expecting. What are those and how can i not see them ?

[image]

```
mysql> select version();
+-----------+
| version() |
+-----------+
| 8.0.12    |
+-----------+

mysql> DESCRIBE users;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| userID      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| username    | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| password    | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| email       | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| avatar      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| admin       | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| createdTime | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name='users' ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION;
+---------------------+
| COLUMN_NAME         |
+---------------------+
| userID              |
| USER                |
| CURRENT_CONNECTIONS |
| username            |
| password            |
| TOTAL_CONNECTIONS   |
| email               |
| avatar              |
| admin               |
| createdTime         |
+---------------------+
10 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

As you can see, I am getting 3 additional columns "USER, CURRENT_CONNECTIONS, TOTAL_CONNECTIONS" which i was not expecting. I need just column names as they are so that i can pass those columns to python for parsing

Is maybe name 'users' clashing with some internal Mysql column or other database?

Comment: There must be another table called `users` in another database. Try using `SELECT column_name, table_schema ...`

Comment: I think there is one in the `performance_schema`, so yeah, it is internal.

Comment: You can add `AND table_schema = 'the_name_of_your_database'` in the `WHERE` clause to get only the columns from the table you need.

Comment: If you are using a single database, use ypercube/tmdag's answer, else use JayRizzo's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @ypercubeᵀᴹ noticed and suggested:

```
SELECT column_name 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_schema = 'mydatabase' 
  AND table_name='users';
```

does the trick

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly common to have happen.

I believe you see these because you have permissions (read) on these as well.

as far as

> What are those and how can i not see them ?

These are system schemas.

### Breakdown

If your not a

1. DBA
2. Concerned about performance, security or maintenance
3. Where your custom snippets live.

They probably will be a waste of your time.

Either way if you do SQL I would urge you to read up on them, as there can be many beneficial items in there.

- [System Schema](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sys-schema.html)
- [MySQL Schema](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/system-database.html)
- [Information Schema](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-information-schema.html)
- [.mysqlworkbench Schema](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-sql-editor-snippets.html)
- [Performance Schema](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/performance-schema.html)

```sql
SELECT column_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA NOT IN ('sys', 'mysql', 
                           'information_schema', 
                           '.mysqlworkbench', 
                           'performance_schema');
```

This works for tables as well.

```
SELECT table_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA NOT IN ('sys', 'mysql',
                           'information_schema',
                           '.mysqlworkbench',
                           'performance_schema');
```

Comment: Suggest `TABLE_SCHEMA NOT IN ('sys', 'mysql', ...)` as more compact.

Comment: Thanks @RickJames, I cleaned it up.  That actually does look better.  Cheers!